# Unable to bind data in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm trying to learn mobile development and got stuck trying to do a recyclerview.

I've set up the data class and also the xml file of the item.

When I try to bind the data to the xml file, in the onBindViewHolder function, the system gives me no option to select which ID I want to bind to.

**Data Class**

```
package com.example.recyclerview1

data class Todo(

    val title: String,
    var isChecked: Boolean

)
```

**XML item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="title"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cbDone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Adapter Class**

```
package com.example.recyclerview1

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class TodoAdapter(

    var todos:List<Todo>

): RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {

    inner class TodoViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_todo,parent,false)
        return TodoViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int { return todos.size}

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {

       holder.itemView.tvTitle << right here I want to select the ID of the TextView, but the IDE does not show me

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `findViewById` method for getting an instance of the view component and then perform some operation on them like this:

```
class TodoAdapter(var todos:List<Todo>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {

    inner class TodoViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) 
    {
        var tvTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle)
        var cbDone: CheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbDone)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
       holder.tvTitle.  // DO YOUR STUFF HERE
    }
}
```

Or you can use `ViewBinding` capabilities for accessing view instances like is written in [this post](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

If you want to perform the whole data binding inside XML, then you need to use `DataBinding` feature. To do that, just follow [this post](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDatabinding/article.html) on how to enable DataBinding and how to use it inside your project.

Comment: Thanks! I've read the documentation and I was able to implement it!

Comment: The general idea of data-binding is NOT having to rely on `findViewById()` and  `ViewBinding` doesn' t answer a data-binding question. That code is completely off-topic, as it has no relation to data-binding. You could as well remove it from the dependencies, when not using it.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I just provided every possible solution to how to set data to the view through the code. Just in case if a question was answered in the wrong way. I still covered data-binding possibility, but I should make it clear that solutions exclude each other.

Answer (score 1):

One cannot data-bind, while the XML will generate no data-binding. That item XML needs `layout` & `data` node and the model class might need `@Bindable` annotations. Better inflate with the data-binding, but for that it would need the be generated.